# How can i replace #define for common swift and objective-c use

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uifont

Our product is written in objective C and we have started writing new features in swift.

This is something written in our global file -

```
#define SPXFontHelveticaBold(SIZE) [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:SIZE]
```

I am unable to use this in my swift class.

Comment: It is a C macro, specifically a function-like C macro. Think about what a function-like C macro does. What's the obvious replacement for a function-like C macro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have replaced my pragma with the following:

```
static inline UIFont* SPXFontHelveticaBold(CGFloat SIZE) { 
  return [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:SIZE]; 
}
```

Answer (score 5):

There is no macro in swift but you can achieve same functionality using following code block, which returns `UIFont`.

```
func SPXFontHelveticaBold (s:CGFloat) -> UIFont{
    return UIFont (name: "Helvetica", size:s )
}
```

or you can define a Helper `struct` which holds such functions as following.

```
struct Helper {
    static func SPXFontHelveticaBold(s: CGFloat) -> UIFont {
    return UIFont (name: "Helvetica", size:s )
}

let font = Helper.SPXFontHelveticaBold(14)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift doesn't support macros. The [Apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html) state that:

> Declare simple macros as global constants, and translate complex macros into functions.

So declare it as a global function and use in same way as ou were using before.

```
func SPXFontHelveticaBold(size: CGFloat) -> UIFont { 
    return UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: size) 
}
```